# Woocommerce redirect loop - NOT SSL RELATED

Tags: wordpress, loops, redirect, woocommerce

so I'm working on a wordpress site (found at nsuited.com) and my problem is that the checkout is causing a redirect loop. I have searched the internet for this problem and it mostly seemed to be related to forcing ssl or using an https wordpress plugin. I am doing neither, and everything was running fine until randomly the redirect started occurring. There's way too much code to post it all, but if there is anything specific you'd like to see let me know. I have tried changing the woocommerce checkout page, which then allowed me to access the checkout page as a page itself but I could not actually checkout from it. If I try to go to whatever page is set to checkout, BAM redirect loop again. I'm at a huge loss and have not been able to find any significant leads from debugging. Please help :(

**EDIT: Also pertinent information - I recently moved my installation from a subfolder to root, though the checkout page was working since I moved installations**

Comment: are you missing a "loop" in the first sentence? and in the title?

Comment: edited it for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I had tried this before without succes:

Add

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');`

to the file "wp-config.php". When I added it initially, I put it at the end to no avail. Put it as the very first line of code for glory.